# Xamarin Studio & Mono running a ASP.NET MVC 3 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, xamarin-studio

I am trying to run a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the latest versions of Xamarin Studio & Mono.

[image: Error Message]

I am stumped as to why this is failing right out of the box.

Comment: Please copy-paste the error message rather than posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do an update after the original installation to get creating a new ASP.NET MVC project to work.